# Perform multiple operations on one element using XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I am pretty new to XSLT stylesheets to transform XML and I need this for a larger BI project.

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<zylab>
    <document version="1.1" guid="{00A4A300-E76C-4373-A35B-1D2F0FF1336B}" date="20110908" time="08:48:52.436" size="2464" path="D:\ZYIMAGE DATA\INDEX DATA\EMD\TXT\2011\36\00000000\" name="00000GFP.TXT" key="">
        <fields>
            <field id="Document_datum">20110830</field>
            <field id="Document_type">value</field>
            ...
        </fields>
    </document>
</zylab>
```

which I would like to transform using XSLT to this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zylab>
    <document version="1.1" guid="{00A4A300-E76C-4373-A35B-1D2F0FF1336B}" date="20110908" time="08:48:52.436" size="2464" path="D:\ZYIMAGE DATA\INDEX DATA\EMD\TXT\2011\36\00000000\" name="00000GFP.TXT" key="" />
    <fields Document_datum="20110830" Document_type="value" ... />
</zylab>
```

So far I have been able to get part of it going, using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <!-- copy node one level up -->
  <xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::field)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- transpose elements to attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:element name="fields">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is the fragments do work independently, but I fail to get it to perform both operations on the same element. 
Output depends on the order of my fragments, the latter is always applied. If I comment out one of them the other seems to work OK.

Does anybody here know how to rework my XSLT to perform both operations on the fields element in order to merge it's fields child elements to attributes and move the fields element to the same leven as the document element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- convert each field to an attribute of parent element (fields)  -->
<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that the content of the `id` attribute is suitable to form a valid attribute name.

---

### Edit:

If you want to move the `fields` element to be a sibling of `document`, add one more template:

```
<!-- move fields to be a sibling of document -->
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="fields"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Edit 2:

> it seems my BI (Microsoft SSIS) XSLT transformation does not like the
>   strip-space macro: But it seems pretty relevant to the transformation
>   as w/o it it does not work at all. Is there any alternative solution?

It's hard to tell what a non-conforming processor will or won't do. Try adding yet one more template:

```
<xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or replace this template:

```
<!-- convert each field to an attribute of parent element (fields)  -->
<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or perhaps remove the whitespace-only text nodes using:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(string)]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is only part of the solution to my problem. Your method works to convert the field elements to attributes of the field attribute, but it still lacks the second part: move the converted fields element up one node to the same level as the document element.

Comment: Do you mean you want `fields` to be a sibling of `document`? Your output is neither here nor there - the `document` element is not closed anywhere.

Comment: And neither is `fields`.

Comment: Oops, in digesting my original pretty large file to a short suitable example for this post I forgot to close the document element (missed the /). I have corrected my opening post.

What I want is to be the fields element at the same level as the document element, so it should be moved up one level and should have field elements merged to attributes of the fields element.

Comment: Sorry to revisit this once more, but it seems my BI (Microsoft SSIS) XSLT transformation does not like the strip-space macro:


But it seems pretty relevant to the transformation as w/o it it does not work at all. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: @jonathan What do you mean by "does not like"? And by "does not work at all"? `xsl:strip-space` removes whitespace-only text nodes from the tree. There should not be any text content, if I understand correctly? Then, add `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` to the stylesheet: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTp.

Comment: @jonathan I have added 3 possible ways to handle the problem. I cannot test any of them using your processor, but they all work using a conforming processor and the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction removed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt replies and suggestions. I worked my way around the problem by using a combination of answers supplied here as well as using part of my original work.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I went with a combination of my original setup and the answers from michael.hor257k, this is the XSLT stylesheet that is working both outside as well as inside my BI solution (SSIS):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- transpose elements to attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="fields">
        <xsl:element name="fields">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{@id}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- move fields to be a sibling of document -->
    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fields"/>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```